# Trouble resampling pandas timeseries from 1min to 5min data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-resample

I have a 1 minute interval intraday stock data which looks like this:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
n = yf.download('^nsei', period= '5d', interval= '1m')
```

I am trying to resample it to '5m' data like this:

```
n = n.resample('5T').agg(dict(zip(n.columns, ['first', 'max', 'min', 'last', 'last', 'sum'])))
```

But it tries to resample the datetime information which is not in my data. The market data is only available till 03:30 PM, but when I look at the resampled dataframe I find its tried to resample for entire 24 hrs.
How do I stop the resampling till 03:30PM and move on to the succeeding date?
Right now the dataframe has mostly NaN values due to this. Any suggestions will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with that `agg()` function. Assuming `'first'` refers to the first quantile and `'last'` to the last quantile  and you want to calculate some statistics per column, I suggest you do the following:

Get your data:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
n = yf.download('^nsei', period= '5d', interval= '1m')
```

Resample your data:

> **Note:** your result is the same as when you resample with `n.resample('5T').first()` but this means every value in the dataframe
> equals the first value from the 5 minute interval consisting of 5
> values. A more logical resampling method is to use the `mean()` or
> `sum()` function as shown below.

If this is data on stock prices it makes more sense to use `mean()`:

```
resampled_df = n.resample('5T').mean()
```

To remove resampled hours that are outside of the working stock hours you have 2 options.

**Option 1:** drop na values:

```
filtered_df = resampled_df.dropna()
```

> **Note:** this will not work if you use sum() since the result won't contain missing values but zeros.

**Option 2** filter based on start and end hour

Get minimum and maximum time of day where data is available as `datetime.time` object:

```
start = n.index.min().time() # 09:15 as datetime.time object
end = n.index.max().time() # 15:29 as datetime.time object
```

Filter dataframe based on start and end times:

```
filtered_df = resampled_df.between_time(start, end)
```

Get the statistics:

```
statistics = filtered_df.describe()
statistics
```

Note that `describe()` will not contain the sum, so in order to add it you could do:

```
statistics = pd.concat([statistics, filtered_df.agg(['sum'])])
statistics
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The agg() is to apply individual method of operation for each column, I used this so that I can get to see the 'candlestick' formation as it is called in stock technical analysis. 
I was able to fix the issue, by dropping the NaN values.